Name and properties of this particular tridiagonal matrix
Let $n$ be a positive integer, define the following tridiagonal matrix:
$$D_n:=\begin{bmatrix}n & n &   &   &  &   &  &   &       \\
1 & n-2 & n-1 &   &   &  &   &   &       \\
  & 2 & n-4 & n-2 &   &  &   &  &        \\
  &   & 3 & n-6 & n-3 &  &   &   &       \\
  &   &   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  &   &     \\
&  &   &   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  &      \\
&&  &   &   & n-1 & 2-n & 1     \\
&&&  &   &   & n & -n  \end{bmatrix}$$
Specifically, $D_n$ is the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ square tridiagonal matrix, whose $(j,k)$-th entry is given by:
$$[D_n]_{j,j}=n-2(j-1),\quad \forall j=1,\dots, n+1$$
$$ [D_n]_{j,j+1}=n-(j-1),\quad \forall j=1,\dots,n-1,$$
$$[D_n]_{j+1,j}=j-1,\quad \forall j=1,\dots,n-1.$$
I wonder whether this specific tridiagonal matrix $D_n$ has a name. Also, I am curious about specific properties of $D_n$. For instance, the determinant of $D_n$. Are there any references to suggest? Thanks.

I don't know of any name.
I get the following values for $\det(D_n)$, $n = 1 \ldots 20$:
$$ -2,\ 0,\ 36,\ 0,\ -1800,\ 0,\ 176400,\ 0,\ -28576800,\ 0,\ 6915585600,\ 0,\ -2337467932800,\ 0,\ 1051860569760000,\ 0,\ -607975409321280000,\ 0,\ 438958245529964160000,\ 0$$
It looks like the determinant is $0$ when $n$ is even, and
$$ (-2)^{(n+1)/2} \prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} (2i+1)^2 $$
when $n$ is odd.  That sequence is OEIS sequence A126934.

Thank you for the reference. Interesting results!
